# WinAPI, рассчитать ширину шрифта для TextOut

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как правильно рассчитать точную ширину выводимого символа текущего шрифта, чтобы вывести текст с помощью TextOut в рабочее окно? Делаю для полосы прокрутки горизонтальной.
P.S.: делал так, но не для каждого символа подходит

```
TEXTMETRIC tm;
int size_x(tm.tmAveCharWidth);  // средняя ширина символа
```

Спасибо

Comment: GetTextExtentPoint32

Comment: @SergeySlepov оживлю вопрос пожалуй. Использую данную функцию, но она не всегда работает так, как надо. Вот у меня есть std::list строк. Я нашёл максимальную строку, вычислил её длину с помощью GetTextExtentPoint32. По формуле длина макс. строки / кол-во символов макс. строки нашёл ширину одного символа. Вроде всё ничего. Но нижний scroll ошибается, и выводит не до конца текст.  Такие неточности всегда, или это я косячу? Могу приложить проект.

Comment: Если вы используете не моноширинный (monospace) шрифт, то ширина символов будет неодинаковая (сравните iiiii и mmmmm), поэтому "усреднение" не подходит.

Comment: Решил проблему поиском максимальной длины строки и выводом всех через DrawText